# How do I run laravel markdown on my textarea

Tags: laravel, markdown, laravel-blade

I have read through https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Markdown/tree/7.1 but I do not seem to understand how I can utillize the information in there to achieve the following:

I have a file called create.blade.php which has a textarea, see down below:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" required name="description" id="description" onfocus="this.select();">{{ old('description',$projectDefaults['description']) }}</textarea>
```

Recently, we recieved a gitlab issue where it was stated that instead of a styled textarea, they want a WYSIWYG editor, but a markdown editor would be fine aswell.

As such, I installed the dependency from Graham Campbell, and I created a filed called "task-create.md.blade.php".

**However, I am totally stuck. I do not seem to understand how I can make the textarea be a markdown editor.**

If anyone does, please do help me out with this. It would be appreciated.

Comment: You want your text area to be a WYSIWYG editor in the same vein as the sample shown here?  https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/textarea  If that's the case, I think the package you linked isn't doing the same thing.

Comment: Yes but the thing is that it needs to save markup, and not HTML like most if not all WYSIWYG editors do.

Answer (score 0):

Switched to ToastUI which automatically binds to existing logic; **Case closed**.